# Extracting Certificate from Keystore on Java 6

Tags: java, keystore, keytool, java-6

I'm facing a problem right now and I can't understand why I can't read a KeyStore on Java 6. The piece code is like this:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(<path to file>);
ks.load(file, <password>);
String alias = (String)ks.aliases().nextElement();

PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey)ks.getKey(alias, ConstantsUtils.CERT_PASS.toCharArray());
Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
```

I'm using this certificate to sign a PDF from Java code, but variables **key** and **chain** stay null, so the keystore can't retreive my private key.

The Keystore was created by keytool importing a certificate with the next line (Windows 7):

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\bin>keytool -importcert -file "<path to cert>" -keystore <path to keystore -alias "<alias>" -keypass <password> -storepass <password>
```

Imported certificate is from a third party, and should work properly. I don't know if is something wrong importing the certificate or if I'm coding something in a bad way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I found the ultimate solution.

My problem was that I had 2 files, one a certificate (we'll call it `certificate.crt`) and the other one was the private key (we'll call it `private_key.pem`). As [EJP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207421/ejp) said previously the problem was around the private key import process. I had 2 different files so I was importing just `certificate.crt` file into a `.jks` file, and `private_key.pem` gave me an error when I tried to import (obviously). So my solution was to merge both files (`certificate.crt` and `private_key.pem`) into one `PKCS#12` file with this command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -inkey private_key.pem -in certificate.cert -export -out certificate.pfx
```

Now, the new `certificate.pfx` is a *keystore* which contains public and private key, correctly formated so, with some changes in my code it was possible to obtain the private key and sign my document:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(<path to .pfx file>);
ks.load(file, <password>);
String alias = (String)ks.aliases().nextElement();

PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey)ks.getKey(alias, ConstantsUtils.CERT_PASS.toCharArray());
Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
```

So thats all. Thank you EJP, I was missunderstanding you, and you made me think in the right way. I was facing this four days so I'm pretty hyped up right now.

Answer (score 2):

You're importing a certificate. Unless it corresponds to a private key already in the KeyStore, and you don't agree to the 'trust CA certs?' prompt, this will create a trusted certificate, and looking for it via a `PrivateKey` will fail.

And if you're importing a certificate from a third party, you won't have their private key, unless they are spectacularly incompetent.

In short what you're doing doesn't make sense.

Comment: It's just a certificate to sign a PDF document, previously generated at Java level, i just need a way to read that and stamp on this document.

Comment: You can't use it to sign anything unless you have a private key. Your whole problem seems radically misconceived.

Comment: The thing is that I imported the certificate (so the private key too) into my KeyStore with keytool, then I want to read that private key to use it to sign my PDF. The problem is that I can't read that PrivateKey although I can open the keystore and into a debugger see all data.

Comment: There's nothing in your question about importing a private key. It mentions *creating* the keystore *by* importing a *certificate*.

Comment: Probally I explained myself bad. I need to access the private key because I have to sign that PDF. I have the **.crt** and **.pem** files, so, how could I access that content from Java?

Comment: Sigh. You haven't shown how you imported the private key. Obviously you did it wrongly, or not at all. Nobody can help until you disclose that.